# Weird lines over a eevee render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have been rendering an image using eevee due to time constraints. Whenever I render an scene from the animation that is above the base plane, i get strange scanlines. These look really bad when the whole animation is played.

Im using blender 2.82.

This is the issue i am getting.
[image: Example of issue with eevee]

Many thanks